# Bootstrap Active Button State Persists

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet, mapbox

I'm using a bootstrap vertical buttons group as a checkbox-style UI to control layers on [this mapbox.js-based interactive map](http://bl.ocks.org/wboykinm/9879313). The layer control functionality works great, but for some reason the buttons:

- Load in the normal state (as they should)
- Go to active state when clicked (as they should)
- Retain the active state color when they are next clicked (sad face emoji)

Looks like this:

[image: bootstrap buttons]

My suspicions are that my onclick function is interfering with the native behavior of a bootstrap button group, but I can't for the life of me figure out how. This is what I currently have for that function, managing both the button class update and the map layer update:

```
link.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
        this.className = 'btn btn-primary';
    } else {
        map.addLayer(layer);
        this.className = 'active btn btn-primary';
    }
};
```

Given that, how can I get my buttons to deselect correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it, just add the `stop()` function to your else statement so that it removes the `active` class from the previous button and add it to the clicked button.

```
 if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
        this.className = 'btn btn-primary';
    } else {
        map.addLayer(layer);
        this.stop().className = 'active btn btn-primary';
    }
```

Comment: I actually managed to get it with the listed solution, but that's great to know about the `stop()` function; it'll come in handy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't really make sense to me why this would be the case, I've solved the problem with a very simple change:

Instead of constructing the buttons with `<button>` elements, I switched them to `<a>` elements. Works perfectly now. If anyone could explain why, I'd love to hear it.